# Retrieve data colors bootstrap theme plotly-dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am building an application using the Plotly-Dash library in Python. I am using bootstrap components with the [Lumen](https://usebootstrap.com/theme/lumen) theme to make everything look nice (For the DCC components, I'm also using this [stylesheet](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AnnMariew/dash-bootstrap-templates@V1.0.6/dbc.min.css), but I don't think it is relevant). Thanks to these stylesheets, my plotly graphs look according to the theme, including data colors (such as the data in pie-charts).

Now I am adding a new graph which displays errors/warnings/valid values. To make these colors intuitive, I am assigning custom colors to the data (errors red, warnings yellow, valid green). I want the shade of these colors to be from the default data colors of the lumen theme, so everything looks consistent.

Now of course I can 'manually' figure out the RGB values by taking screenshots, checking the RGB and hardcoding them in python. However, I'm looking for a better way. Is there maybe a python function with which I can retrieve the lumen default data color values? Or can I maybe find them in the css somewhere? (I'm far from an expert in CSS)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

### Guess from the CSS file

[Download the Lumen package using the link you provided](https://usebootstrap.com/download-theme/lumen), unzip it, then open the `lumen/theme/boostrap.css` file. Some styles are pretty self-explanatory, for example

```
    .btn-warning {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #ff851b;
      border-color: #ff7701;
    }
```

which contains the colors defining the style of the warning button. There are similar definitions for `.btn-success`, `.btn-danger`, etc.

---

### Be certain by inspecting element

[Access the Lumen live preview from the link you provided](https://usebootstrap.com/preview/lumen). Right-click any element for which you want know the style details, then select *Inspect*. At the bottom of the pane that appears to the right, on the *Styles* tab, you will see the cascade of styles applied to the inspected element. You will most probably find the answer you want in one of the first few styles. For the warning button, [see example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijH49.png). You are most probably looking for `background-color` in `.btn-warning`.

---

Regardless of the method, if you want the RGB representation of the colors, you can use a [converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html) to convert hexadecimal color codes to RGB.